# AWS sample template vpc+multiple subnets not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I'm deploying an apparently simple CloudFormation template from AWS samples: https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-ap-northeast-1/vpc_multiple_subnets.template

As stated, it should "...create a VPC with multiple subnets. The first subnet is public and contains the load balancer, the second subnet is private and contains an EC2 instance behind the load balancer."

However, I can't reach the instance through the balancer public DNS Name.

The balancer

- shows the instance as "OutOfService" (but it's running)
- has a health checker and listener on port 80.
- run inside a vpc and the vpc has attached an IGW
- run in the same AZ as the instance
- has a security group with inbound and outbound HTTP access rule from anywhere

the instance

- is in a private subnet of the same VPC
- has a security group that accepts inbound HTTP traffic from the balancer security group and outbound to anywhere

If I curl the balancer I get 503, like if the traffic is reaching the balancer but not the instance.

I'm at loss, I don't know how to troubleshoot more than this.

EDIT: maybe that instance has no web server in it?

Comment: It would be easier if you'd included the page that documents what the template does. Looks to me like it's launching a standard Amazon Linux 2 image, which doesn't have a web server installed. You probably need to update the template with an AMI that has a web server installed listening on port 80.